# Error while flagging : Your message must be longer than 10 characters

Tags: support, flags, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to merge my Stack Overflow account https://stackoverflow.com/users/1294802 with my other account (unregistered) https://stackoverflow.com/users/1194859/unni-kris. 
But when I am trying to flag one of my post for moderator attention for merging the account, I am getting an error
**"Your message must be longer than 10 characters."**

I have added more than ten characters.
Format : Please help to merge my **account1 link** to **account2 link**

Please help.  This happens in IE7.

Comment: So, nave question follows: What did you type in as message?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it means that your message must be longer than 10 characters.

Comment: Ok - then this is a bug, right?  What browser / version?

Comment: i am using IE 7 browser

Comment: I have added the [bug] tag for you.  I cannot reproduce the problem in IE9 set to IE7 mode.

Comment: IE7 is now unsupported by us - is there any way for you to upgrade or use a different browser? In other news, I've merged your two users, so at least that part is done.

Comment: @Jarrod thanks for merging the accounts. I wil start using firfox then.

Answer (score 2):

Try writing more than 10 characters into the text field, like e.g:

> Please merge this account with my other account at [link]

Comment: I'm trying to think of *how* one would request this in less than 10 characters...

Comment: @jadarnel27 `merge plx`

Comment: I guess it might be a bug (according to the OPs update), although I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: There should be a canned summary like "Fix typos".

Comment: @giorgian If you're using flags to ask mods to fix typos, you're doing it wrong in the first place